# Translate task result

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have an external library that returns `Task<T>`.  My library wraps this call and does a translation and returns `Task<T2>`.  How can I create my Task that will run on completion of Task without using a `.Wait()` or `.Result`?  Feels like a `.ContinueWith()` should do it, but I'm struggling with the syntax since ContineWith() seems to be driven by the  of the antecedent task, whereas I want to transalte to T2.  `Task.FromResult<T2>()` would work if I used a .Result on the antecedent, but again, I'd ideally like to chain.

```
Task<Hamburger> GetHambrugerAsync()
{
   Task<Cow> t1 = _extlib.GetCowAsync();
   return Task.Factory.StartNew<Hamburger>(() => 
   {
      t1.Wait();
      return Hamburger();
   });
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add a sample code of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a `T2 GetT2(T1 input)` function.

You have a couple of ways:

```
public Task<T2> GetT2Async(Task<T1> task)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(t => GetT2(t.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}
```

Or, using `async`:

```
public async Task<T2> GetT2Async(Task<T1> task)
{
    return GetT2(await task); // You may want to add .ConfigureAwait(false)
}
```

Both ways will return a `Task<T2>`, which will perform a conversion from a `Task<T1>` *after* that task is complete.

---

With your example:

```
async Task<Hamburger> GetHambrugerAsync()
{
   Cow cow = await _extlib.GetCowAsync();
   return new Hamburger(cow);
}
```

Or:

```
Task<Hamburger> GetHambrugerAsync()
{
   Task<Cow> cowTask = _extlib.GetCowAsync();
   return cowTask.ContinueWith(t => new Hamburger(t.Result, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion));
}
```